# WebBrowser Doubleclick inside splitcontainer.panel is throwing an error : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException HRESULT: 0x800A025E

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, double-click

I am having some weird problem with implementing a webbrowser control inside the splitcontainer.panel.
throwing the above error. I have tried the same coding bringing it outside the splitcontainer.panel; then all working fine.

upon loading the webpage, im expecting to click on a word on the webpage then, it should select the double clicked word and show it on the messagebox.

I would really appreciate if any of our expert here could help me out on this.

here is my sample coding:
PS: Its crashing at range1.select()
Update : Also I noticed upon further testing, that If I don't use dynamic control for webBrowser then it is working fine too. 
But dynamic tab, panel and webBrowser is one of my criteria as well.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public static string lbname;
    public WebBrowser br1 = new WebBrowser();
    public WebBrowser br2 = new WebBrowser();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var tab = new TabPage("1");
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
        tab.Select();

        var pnl = new Panel();
        tab.Controls.Add(pnl);
        pnl.Controls.Add(br1);

        Uri url1 = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

        br1.Url = url1;
        br1.DocumentCompleted += Browser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    private void Browser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        br1.Document.DetachEventHandler("ondblclick", Document_DoubleClick);
        br1.Document.AttachEventHandler("ondblclick", Document_DoubleClick);
    }

    private void Document_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc1 = br1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = doc1.selection;

        if (currentSelection != null)
        {

            IHTMLTxtRange range1 = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;

            if (range1 != null)
            {
                range1.expand("word");
                range1.select();
                MessageBox.Show("selected text" + range1.text);
            }
        }
    }
```

=====
And of course I have already referenced the mshtml, and SHDocVw because it is working except the splitcontainer.panel.

Answer (score 0):

Upon spending much time to resolve this issue, I have decided to eliminate the SplitContainer and use the Panels instead. Not sure why, but determined the SplitContainer is the issue and managed to work around by using the Panels.